# Asp.net - Create html from server vs using json

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, json, custom-controls

My question is regardign performance of the web page. I need to create a treeview which will display large data (10,000) nodes. The way asp.net reeeview renders itself it not good for performance as it uses Table tag. I created a custom control to make a treeview using div and spans. I can do that by 2 methods:

1. Create a custom control where i will override the render and put my own html which will get on the page. This will have performance impact when connection speed is slow. But other i guess the performance will be godd as the browser will just render it. No JS to run.
2. Create a json object and render it on page (in which case, page size would be lesser then the above page). But IE6-8 do not support javascript hardware accelerator and thus would take time to run the js to make the object.

So my question is which one would be better?? My users have 3 mbps speed and thus speed does not matter as such.

Comment: Is this one parent with 10,000 nodes?  Or you have a possible 10,000 nodes to display?  If it's nested nodes, I'd go with option #2.

Answer (score 2):

Well, unless user is rainman, it is very unlikely, that he will analyze 10000 nodes at a glance, so why not to make those nodes load on demand (in case tree is very deep - load when node is expanded, in case tree is very long - load on scroll or smth)?
Telerik demo sample: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/treeview/ajaxloading

Comment: User wants to see it in the same state it was when he viewed last. The expanded remains expanded and collapsed remains collapsed. So lazy loading is not feasible

Comment: Well, that may be requires more complex implementation, but my offer should be still valid - you should load only that, what is visible at current moment.

Answer (score 0):

It's not only matter of bandwidth . But such size can affect to memory leak in client.
I would create a separate Web Method that returns JSON and will build Tree using some javascript component such as ExtJs

Comment: That again is using table/tr and td to render. And this will make it again slow on IE8

Comment: Please check their demo, it's amazing http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/tree/treegrid.html

Comment: Again the same. Its lazy loading which i cant use